# css dynamic nth-child selector

Tags: html, css

I have this element

```
<div>
<li>
item 1
</li>
<li>
item 2
</li>
<li>
item 3
</li>
<li>
item 4
</li>
</div>
```

and I always want to show the first two, hence I do

```
li {
  &:nth-child(1),
  &:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

but if the item list got added 1 item, the visible item will be 3, is 
there any way I can always show 2? I guess I need to modify my css?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. A `<li>` cannot be the child of a `<div>`.

Comment: give it a class or an ID, then create a CSS rule for that (BTW: With the rule above, you are *hiding*  the first two `li`s, not showing them...)

Comment: @OP you want to show the first 2 elements? like `item1` and `item1`?

Comment: @Manjuboyz item 1, item 2

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `li` means 'list-item', so the element is only valid in a list (`ol` or `ul`). In my example, I've therefore changed the `div` to an `ul` (unordered list) element.

Secondly, your code seems to always hide the first two elements, but you said you always want to show the first two. To so this, hide all `li` elements by default using `display: none`, and only `display: block` the first two:

```css
li {
  display: none;
}

li:nth-child(1), li:nth-child(2) {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ul>
```